# somthing simular to get() for arrays in java?

Tags: java, arrays

Is there something similar to the get() method for arrayList that I can use for arrays? I am trying to take the first value from array1, add it to the first value form array 2 and add that to the first value form array three, then div by three to find the average. I once I have that I repeat for the second and so on, these are then placed in a new array.

```
String[] Array1=
{
new String("Adam  "),new String("Smith "),new String("Jones "),new String("Becky   "),new String("Taylor")
};




Integer[] Array2=
{
new Integer(90),new Integer(89),new Integer(86),new Integer(76),new Integer(95)
};


Integer[] Array3=
{
    new Integer(92),new Integer(79),new Integer(85),new Integer(90),new Integer(87)
};

Integer[] Array4=
{
    new Integer(93),new Integer(80),new Integer(90),new Integer(87),new Integer(92)
};

Integer[] Array5=
{
    new Integer(90),new Integer(77),new Integer(86),new Integer(92),new Integer(89)
};
```

Comment: Use a for loop and you're done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can just access it by index:

```
array1[0] // first element of array1
array1[1] // second element of array1
.....
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something along the lines of:

```
String adam = Array1[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(Array2[0] + Array3[0] + Array4[0] + Array5[0])/4
```

Comment: make it general for all the items in the array

Answer (score 0):

The `get(index)` method of an array is just `[index]`:

```
String s = anArray[0];
// equivalent to
String s = anArraylist.get(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

The built-in `[]` operator is the equivalent of `List.get`.  Something like

```
array4[i] = (array1[i] + array2[i] + array3[i]) / 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < cantArrays;i++)
{
     int sum = 0;
     double avg;
     for(int j = 0; j < Array1.lenght;j++)
     {
         sum = Array2[j] + Array3[j] + Array4[j] + Array5[j];
         avg = sum / 4;
     }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sample code is very constructor-happy. This should be functionally equivalent:

```
String[] Array1 = {"Adam  "), "Smith ", "Jones ", "Becky   ", "Taylor" };
Integer[] Array2 = { 90, 89, 86, 76, 95 };
Integer[] Array3 = { 92, 79, 85, 90, 87 };
Integer[] Array4 = { 93, 80, 90, 87, 92 };
Integer[] Array5 = { 90, 77, 86, 92, 89 };
```

As others said, you want the array[index] operator to get an item from an array.